# two classes with similar attributes except one of the attributes is different

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

```
class Air:
    def __init__(self,supplier,delivery,ensurance):
        self.supplier = supplier
        self.delivery = delivery
        self.ensurance = ensurance
    def rate_for_custom(self):
        return (self.supplier + self.delivery + self.ensurance)
class Sea:
    def __init__(self,supplier,delivery,ensurance,port_tax):
        self.supplier = supplier
        self.delivery = delivery
        self.ensurance = ensurance
        self.port_tax = port_tax
    def rate_for_custom(self):
        return (self.supplier + self.delivery + self.ensurance + self.port_tax)
```

so i'm trying to write a program that calculates the import taxes in israel.

There are two types: one in the sea and one in the air

they both share the same attributes except Sea needs to be calculated with another attribute.

I'm feeling like my code is not good(i'm new to pragramming started a week ago)

is it fine to use two classes in this case? if not what is the solution (by stil using OOP because I need to practice with it)

Answer (score 1):

You can move common parts to a common parent class:

```
class Transport:
    def __init__(self,supplier,delivery,ensurance):
        self.supplier = supplier
        self.delivery = delivery
        self.ensurance = ensurance
    def rate_for_custom(self):
        return (self.supplier + self.delivery + self.ensurance)

class Air(Transport):
    pass

class Sea(Transport):
    def __init__(self,supplier,delivery,ensurance,port_tax):
        super().__init__(supplier, delivery, ensurance)
        self.port_tax = port_tax
    def rate_for_custom(self):
        return super().rate_for_custom() + self.port_tax
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. does the super().__init__. can be replaced with Transport.__init__ ? that's how I learned it so i'm trying to understand if it's the same or not

Comment: It can. Using `super()` is less prone to mistakes if you decide to rename your parent class.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to learn OOP, then you can start to see the concept of inheritance. Here is an example:

```
# generic class
class Custom:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        # collect all given parameters:
        self.args = args

    def rate_for_custom(self):
        # just sum all numbers in given parameter:
        return sum(self.args)

class Sea(Custom):
    def __init__(self,supplier=0,delivery=0,insurance=0, port_tax = 0):
        # Call Custom class and provide all relevant parameters:
        super().__init__(supplier, delivery, insurance, port_tax) 


class Air(Custom):
    def __init__(self,supplier=0, delivery=0, insurance=0):
        # Call Custom class and provide all relevant parameters:
        super().__init__(supplier, delivery, insurance )        


print(Custom(100,50,25).rate_for_custom())
# 175

print(Air(supplier=100,delivery=50,insurance=25).rate_for_custom())
# 175

print(Sea(supplier=100,delivery=50,insurance=25,port_tax=25).rate_for_custom())
# 200
```

`Custom`class is doing all the job, by summing all parameters it receives in **init**(). You can call this class providing the values to sum :`Custom(100,50,25).rate_for_custom()`
Two other classes `Air`and `Sea` are inheriting from the `Custom`class and are just an interface. Using them allows you to use keyword arguments instead of simple arguments: `Sea(supplier=100,delivery=50,insurance=25,port_tax=25)` which is more friendly.

Comment: *args in the custom class will be saved as a list ?

Comment: @liamlasry *args corresponds to the class arguments in a tuple, so like a list but immutable (not changeable, if you prefer).